# Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, frameworks, lambda, entity

I am using EF 4 but it is giving me error when I try to order my list.

```
Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.
```

This is my code to get the experssion by entering the property name, example below get the Customer Name

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "N");

var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>
            (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, "Name"), typeof(object)), param);
```

And my EF code is

```
GetObjectSet<T>().AsQueryable().OrderBy(sortExpression).Skip(0).Take(5);
```

I know it is some sort of casting problem with EF because it works without the EF but it gives me this error when i hook it up with EF. Is there a work around or something because i don't want to use LINQ.

Comment: You're already using LINQ. `AsQueryable`, `OrderBy`, `Skip`, and `Take` are all LINQ operators.

Comment: What I ment was LINQ to SQL not LINQ sorry. If you use LINQ to SQL my above code works. It dosen't work only in EF.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem, and solved by the following code:

```
IQueryable<T> result = DbSet.AsQueryable<T>();
var classPara = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
var pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortPara);
result = result.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(
                    Expression.Call(
                        typeof(Queryable),
                        "OrderBy",
                        new Type[] { typeof(T), pi.PropertyType },
                        result.Expression,
                        Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(classPara , pi), classPara ))
                    );
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this post was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220155/linq-entity-framework-generic-filter-method/3220297#3220297) addresses what you're trying to do in the easiest possible way.

Comment: That was not what I was looking for. I think the problem is when I query using the Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>. I don't think the entity framework allow object to be cast as objects to database types.

Comment: Take a step back and describe *what* you're trying to do, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the method that solved it was:

```
using System; 
 using System.Collections.Generic; 
 using System.Linq; 
 using System.Linq.Expressions; 


public class GenericSorter<T> {
public IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> source, string sortBy, string sortDirection)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

    var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>
        (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortBy), typeof(object)), param);

    switch (sortDirection.ToLower())
    {
        case "asc":
            return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy<T, object>(sortExpression);
        default:
            return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderByDescending<T, object>(sortExpression);

    } 
}
```

}

Then you can call it when you perform the query as:

```
var entity = nameof(DBOEntity.Property);
var order = "asc";
var query = dc.EntityDataSet.AsExpandable().OrderByDynamic(entity, order);
```

I hope this helps you!